# how to escape dot "." character in Ansible variable

Tags: ansible

```
  vars:
    variable: [{
        "b.test": "test1",
        "host": "host1"
        },
        {
        "b.test": "test2",
        "host": "host2"
        }]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg:  "{{item.host}}"
      loop: "{{variable}}"

    - debug:
        msg:  "{{item.b.test}}"
      loop: "{{variable}}"
```

above is my current playbook. 
When I run the above playbook, as expected, the fist debug returns the vlalue stored in the key `host`

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'b.test': 'test1', 'host': 'host1'}) => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'b.test': 'test2', 'host': 'host2'}) => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
```

but I am not able to figure out how to access the value in `b.test` -- i get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'b'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/cmdb/playbooks/dot.yml': line 25, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I tried using the `\` to escape the **dot** but did not work.. 
I also found this page: [Ansible jinja2 escape dotted key in selectattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989989/ansible-jinja2-escape-dotted-key-in-selectattr)
but I have no clue in what is going in there and what really is happening.

please let me know how to go about finding a solution for this, been looking but nothing really has panned out so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables). Put the key into brackets `item['b.test']`. For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    variable:
      - b.test: test1
        host: host1
      - b.test: test2
        host: host2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var:  item['b.test']
      loop: "{{ variable }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'b.test': 'test1', 'host': 'host1'}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    b.test: test1
    host: host1
  item['b.test']: test1
ok: [localhost] => (item={'b.test': 'test2', 'host': 'host2'}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    b.test: test2
    host: host2
  item['b.test']: test2
```

Comment: awesome that worked, I checked it off as the right answer. 
and I had thought I tried that as well, but maybe I did not in the right format. Regardless thank you very much for your help.